# How to align text inside a div with margin?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a child div whose text I want to position to the bottom left.

I am trying to apply "margin-top:10%" to the text in my div, but the whole  image is getting "margin-top:10%" applied to it. How can I align the text like I want?

```css
#slide1_div1{
    height: 60%;
    background-image: url(../images/Executive3.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div id="slide1_div1">
    <div style="color:yellow;background-color:black;margin-top:10%;">
      Room starting at just INR 1800
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Try using padding instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'padding' insted:

```
 <div id="slide1_div1">
    <div style="color:yellow;background-color:black;padding-top:10%;">
      Room starting at just INR 1800
    </div>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sv8yuph6/

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/30gm2hdt/

```
<div id="slide1_div1">
    <div style="color:yellow;background-color:black;margin-top:10%;position:absolute; bottom:0;">
      Room starting at just INR 1800
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#slide1_div1 {
  height: 60%;
  width: auto;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/350x150");
  background-size:100% 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```